# Flutter Camera Plugin don't change resolution to UltraHigh

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, camera, resolution

I'm using the camera 0.5.8+7 for Flutter and trying the example code, I can't change the resolution to ultrahigh, the max resolution i get is 1920x1080. I'm running the app on Samsung A10S. How do I get a better resolution?